# I cant connect mysql

Tags: mysql

When I try to enter the root user from MySQL Workbench and manually enter it, I get the following error:

> your connection attempt failed for user root to the mysql server
> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am using mysql `-u root` code when I want to connect to MySQL via cmd and I get an error in it:

```
mysql: Unknown operating system character set 'cp857'.
mysql: switch to the default character set of 'utf8mb4'.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access was denied for the user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: No)
```

I get a similar error when I try to log in using a password, the only thing that changes is (using password: YES).
What had I better do?

Comment: You should figure out the correct password for the `root` user.

Comment: are you using the right password? Have you tried resetting it?

Answer (score 2):

Issue with your password so simply *change mysql root password*.
here command
**mysql -u root**
then
**mysqladmin -u root password [newpassword]**
may help you this.
thanks